# Triggering Worksheet_Change by deleting content of a merged cell

Tags: vba, excel

I've made a piece of code that, when the cell L3 changes, it in turn changes a range of cells, depending on the content of L3.

L3 is a merged cell that spans from L3 to N4, and the code works fine in spite of this, right until the case where the user deletes the content rather than entering something new.

The following code works perfectly fine for unmerged cells:

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

        If Target.Address = Range("L3").Address Then

             If Range("L3") = Sheets("Formatering").Range("F27") Then
                 Tankpladser = "Vælg Tank"

             ElseIf Range("L3") = Sheets("Formatering").Range("F28") Then
                 Range("E11") = Sheets("Formatering").Range("L3")
                 Range("G11") = Sheets("Formatering").Range("L4")
                 Range("I11") = Sheets("Formatering").Range("L5")
                 Range("K11") = Sheets("Formatering").Range("L6")
            ElseIf Range("L3") = "" Then
                 Range("E11:E12,G11:G12,I11:I12,K11:K12").ClearContents
            End If
        End If
End Sub
```

The problem is that Range("L3") is a merged cell, and is actually Range("L3:N4"). This causes a problem when checking if the cell is blank after deleting the content of the cell.

I am now looking for a way to make something along the lines of this work:

```
ElseIf Range("L3").MergeArea.Cells(1,1).Value = "" Then
    Range("E11:E12,G11:G12,I11:I12,K11:K12") = ""
End If
```

Comment: try `ElseIf Range("L3")(1) = "" Then`

Comment: Still no response from it. Again, it works fine if I select a blank space from the dropdown. It's as if simply hitting delete doesn't really clean out all the cells in L3:N4

Comment: I loaded a merged cell with data validation.  both selecting the blank from the list and deleting the cell fired the change and correctly fired the code in the if.  not sure why yours does not.

Comment: Me neither, but thank you for trying. I am really starting to hate merged cells. The answer by Sktneer seems to work though.

Comment: I know why.  When you make a change to the merged cell with the data validation the target cell is only L3 but when you delete it the address is L3:N4.  So you never get past the first If.

Comment: I did not have the first If in my trials.  It was not till I added `Debug.Print Target.Address` that I saw that the addresses were different depending on the way the data was filled or deleted.

Comment: Ah, that makes (kind of) sense. At least why it causes the error, not that it changes the adress based on the way I fill out the cell. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: In general, always try to avoid merged cells.  They are almost never necessary, and working with them in VBA (and formulas) is often a nightmare.

Comment: No kidding. They really are the worst. Sadly I'm working with a sheet whose setup is not up to me, but to my employer, so there isn't much I can do to avoid them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may try something like this...

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("L3").MergeArea) Is Nothing Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    If Range("L3") = Sheets("Formatering").Range("F27") Then
        Tankpladser = "Vælg Tank"

    ElseIf Range("L3") = Sheets("Formatering").Range("F28") Then
        Range("E11") = Sheets("Formatering").Range("L3")
        Range("G11") = Sheets("Formatering").Range("L4")
        Range("I11") = Sheets("Formatering").Range("L5")
        Range("K11") = Sheets("Formatering").Range("L6")
    ElseIf Range("L3") = "" Then
        Range("E11:E12,G11:G12,I11:I12,K11:K12").ClearContents
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End If
End Sub
```